# Multiply rows in dataframe, then sum them together Python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a function to apply to this table

```
F(x) = 1.5*x1 + 2*x2 - 1.5*x3
```

Where xi, i = 1,2,3, is the column value.

And I have the following table below.

```
X1    | X2   | X3
------|------|------
20    |15    |12    
30    |17    |24    
40    |23    |36
```

The desired output that I would like is the following below, where I apply the function to each row, taking the value in each column and applying it to the function iteratively then receiving value as a sum and another column appended onto the dataframe.

```
X1    | X2   | X3   |F(X)
------|------|------|------
20    |15    |12    |42
30    |17    |24    |43
40    |23    |36    |52
```

Is there a way to do this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this ?

```
df['F(x)']=df.mul([1.5,2,-1.5]).sum(1)
df
Out[1076]: 
   X1  X2  X3  F(x)
0  20  15  12  42.0
1  30  17  24  43.0
2  40  23  36  52.0
```

Comment: Welp, that's much shorter than my own answer to this question. Works well too.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer, don't want to leave mighty @Wen high and dry.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Found a sample code to solve my problem.

```
var1 = 1.5
var2 = 2
var3 = -1.5
def calculate_fx(row):
return (var1 * row['X1']) + (var2 * row['X2']) + (var3 * row['X3'])

#function_df is the predefined dataframe
function_df['F(X)'] = function_df.apply(calculate_fx, axis=1)
function_df
```